# Access json values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, arrays

I want to retrive trend values from the json array retrieved from the twitter api. I require the top 5 trend names.

**Json response**

```
[{
    "trends": [
        {
            "name": "#NationalTellAGirlSheIsBeautifulDay",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23NationalTellAGirlSheIsBeautifulDay",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "%23NationalTellAGirlSheIsBeautifulDay",
            "events": null
        },
        {
            "name": "#YouKnowYouInTheHoodWhen",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23YouKnowYouInTheHoodWhen",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "%23YouKnowYouInTheHoodWhen",
            "events": null
        },
        {
            "name": "#DünyaFenerbahçelilerGünüKutluOlsun",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23D%C3%BCnyaFenerbah%C3%A7elilerG%C3%BCn%C3%BCKutluOlsun",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "%23D%C3%BCnyaFenerbah%C3%A7elilerG%C3%BCn%C3%BCKutluOlsun",
            "events": null
        },
        {
            "name": "#IndonesianTeenager",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23IndonesianTeenager",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "%23IndonesianTeenager",
            "events": null
        },
        {
            "name": "#bpk13",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23bpk13",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "%23bpk13",
            "events": null
        },
        {
            "name": "HaykırırımAşkımıSana BEŞİKTAŞdiye",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Hayk%C4%B1r%C4%B1r%C4%B1mA%C5%9Fk%C4%B1m%C4%B1Sana+BE%C5%9E%C4%B0KTA%C5%9Ediye%22",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "%22Hayk%C4%B1r%C4%B1r%C4%B1mA%C5%9Fk%C4%B1m%C4%B1Sana+BE%C5%9E%C4%B0KTA%C5%9Ediye%22",
            "events": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Vogue Korea",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Vogue+Korea%22",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "%22Vogue+Korea%22",
            "events": null
        },
        {
            "name": "PNG",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=PNG",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "PNG",
            "events": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Makueni",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Makueni",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "Makueni",
            "events": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Jeremy Kyle",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Jeremy+Kyle%22",
            "promoted_content": null,
            "query": "%22Jeremy+Kyle%22",
            "events": null
        }
    ],
    "as_of": "2013-07-19T09:23:13Z",
    "created_at": "2013-07-19T09:14:10Z",
    "locations": [
        {
            "name": "Worldwide",
            "woeid": 1
        }
    ]
}]
```

**jQuery Code**

```
 $.getJSON("url",function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

How can I retrieve the values from the object in the success function?

Comment: It appears you didn't even try googling how to access any sort of json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The twitter API sends back an object containing the trend data.

So to get each trend name it would be like below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data[0].trends.length; i++) {
   console.log(data[0].trends[i].name);
}
```

This would log all the trend names out. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
var topTrends = [];
foreach(var i in data[0].trends) {
   var dat = data[0].trends[i].name;
   topTrends.push(dat);
   if(topTrends.length == 5) {
      return topTrends; 
   } 
}
```

This will serve your cause

Answer (score 0):

```
var names ='';
```

for(var i = 0; i < data[0].trends.length; i++) {

```
if( i < 5){

      alert(data[0].trends[i].name);

      names += "| +"data[0].trends[i].name"";
}
```

}

names = names.substr(1);